# How do I get embedded MIDI files to play in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, multimedia, midi

When I click play on this site (http://tones.wolfram.com/), nothing happens. If I download the file to disk, there are several applications installed that play just fine. How do I get chrome to act as expected here?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the instructions here:

[How can I set up my Linux/Unix machine to play WolframTones compositions?](http://tones.wolfram.com/tsfaqs/linux/pluginsetup.html)

?

Comment: Link is dead...